# "Could not initialize proxy - no Session"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, junit

I'm getting the following error message when trying to run a JUnit test via Spring, JPA and Java:

"Could not initialize proxy - no Session"

The tests are for a domain class (let's call it FirstDomainClass). The FirstDomainClass class has a number of fields, including one which is linked through to another domain class in a many-to-one relationship:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "SECOND_DOMAIN_CLASS")
private SecondDomainClass secondDomainClass;
```

I found I had to use FetchType.EAGER because otherwise the SecondDomainClass object would not be populated when I retrieved an instance of FirstDomainClass.

The DAO implementation class for FirstDomainClass has each method prefixed with a @Transactional annotation:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
public void store(FirstDomainClass firstDomainClass) {
    entityManager.persist(firstDomainClass);
}
```

I then use Spring to wire everything together, including a bean definition of my DAO implementation which is then @Autowired into my JUnit class. The test class creates some data in the database via a @Before method and clears it out afterwards with an @After method.

The class is prefixed with

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = false)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { ... list of config files... })
```

... and the test looks like this:

```
@Test
public void testStore() {
    SecondDomainClass second = secondDomainClassDao.get(... object created in @Before method... );

    FirstDomainClass first = new FirstDomainClass();
    first.setSecondDomainClass(second);
    ... other setting...
    firstDomainClassDao.store(first);

    FirstDomainClass newFirst = firstDomainClassDao.get(... criteria to retrieve object created by store()... );

    ... assertions here...
}
```

When the test runs as part of an automated build process, it fails with the message detailed above. The stacktrace identifies that the error occurs when the primary key of the SecondDomainClass object is accessed.

Versions: Java 1.7 / JUnit 4.10 / JPA 2 / Spring 3.2.2 / Hibernate 4.1.7

Many thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: It seems the SecondDomainClass is lazy loaded, but the session has been closed when you want to access it's fields. What if you remove the TransactionCOnfiguration annotation on the test class or add a Transactional annotation on the test method?

Comment: Just wondering, do you ever call second.setFirstDomainClass()?

Comment: I don't call second.setFirstDomainClass(), no. SecondDomainClass can exist independently of FirstDomainClass, but not vice versa.

Comment: If I remove the test class's "TransactionConfiguration" annotation, I get the same error. If I add a "Transactional" annotation to the test method, the test hangs indefinitely when executing the script which removes the test data from the database.

Answer (score 0):

> *"could not initialize proxy [...] - no Session"* error

Use the following annotation on the service method:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
```