# Hibernate: LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

board entity and member entity is not association mapping

board entity class...

```
@Entity(name = "BOARD")
@Table
@SequenceGenerator(name = "BOARD_SEQ_GENERATOR"
                    , sequenceName = "BOARD_SEQ"
                    , initialValue = 1)
public class BoardEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE
                    , generator = "BOARD_SEQ_GENERATOR")
    private long idx;

    @Lob
    private String contents;

    private String title;

    private long insNo;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date insDate;

    private long uptNo;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date uptDate;

    @Transient
    private String insName;
    .....
    getter / setter
```

member entity class...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MEMBER")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "MEMBERIDX_SEQ_GENERATOR"
                    , sequenceName = "MEMBERIDX_SEQ"
                    , initialValue = 1)
public class MemberEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE
                    , generator = "MEMBERIDX_SEQ_GENERATOR")
    private long memberIdx;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String pwd;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int age;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date insDate;
    .....
    getter / setter
```

MemberRepository class code...

```
@Repository
public interface MemberRepository extends JpaRepository<MemberEntity, Long> {

    @Query("select m from MemberEntity m where m.id=:id")
    public MemberEntity getMemberIDbyId(@Param("id") String id);
}
```

MemberService class code...

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class MemberService {

    @Autowired private MemberRepository memberRepository;

    public void addMember(MemberEntity member) {
        memberRepository.save(member);
    }

    public MemberEntity getMember(Long memberIdx) {
        return memberRepository.getOne(memberIdx);
    }
}
```

BoardController class code...

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/board")
public class BoardController {

    @Autowired 
    private BoardService boardService;

    @Autowired
    private MemberService memberService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String BoardList(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, Model model) throws Exception {

        List<BoardEntity> resutlList = boardService.getBoardList();

        //resutlList.forEach(System.out::println);

        for (BoardEntity item : resutlList) {
            MemberEntity memberEntity = memberService.getMember(item.getInsNo());
            item.setInsName(memberEntity.getName());
        }

        model.addAttribute("boardList", resutlList);

        return "board/boardList";
    }
}
```

ErrorMessage

> 심각: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path []
>   threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy
>   - no Session] with root cause org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy
>   - no Session  at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:147)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:260)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:68)
>     at
>   com.knk.spring4.entity.member.MemberEntity_$$_jvst201_0.getName(MemberEntity_$$_jvst201_0.java)
>     at
>   com.knk.spring4.controller.board.BoardController.BoardList(BoardController.java:70)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

[image: ERD]

The InsNo and UptNo columns in the Board table contain the MemberIdx values of the member who created and edited the post.

I want to import the ID column of the membership table using the InsNo column or the UptNo column of the bulletin board table.

How do I handle the current error if there is no mapping of associations?

Comment: See my answer on ["Could not initialize proxy - no Session"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714731/could-not-initialize-proxy-no-session/75233630#75233630).

Answer (score 3):

It's because you are using the `JpaRepository.getOne` method to retrieve members. According to the [JPA repository Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#getOne-ID-) :

> T getOne(ID id)
>
> Returns a reference to the entity with the given identifier.
>
> See Also:
>
> EntityManager.getReference(Class, Object)

And and the [EntityManager Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getReference-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object-):

> T getReference(Class entityClass,
>                      Object primaryKey)
>
> Get an instance, whose state may be lazily fetched.

Basically `JpaRepository.getOne` doesn't return an object build from a fetched  database record but a **proxy referencing the record** that will get initialize on the first access to any member other than the refering id. So when you call `MemberEntity.getName` when the Session/EntityManager you get the LazyException when the proxy try to fetch the record.

To fix it in your case you have multiple option:

1. Using a [OpenSessionInViewFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html) to keep the session on the entire request, this one is an anti-pattern and not recommended
2. You can use the Hibernate annotation `@Lazy` and set the lazy property to false (it works in other similar case, not sure it will works here). Cons here is the annotation is not a JPA's one, so you'll tie your project tot he implementation and not the specification.
3. You can manually trigger the proxy when the Session/EntityManager is still open by calling any member.
4. The `CrudReposiroty.findOne` method return the object and not a proxy if i remember correctly.